# PHP how to use idn_to_ascii for mail adresses

Tags: php, email, idn

since it's possible to have Umlaute (e.g. öäü) in the local part of an email address I need to convert them to ascii because Zend-Mail is not able to handle it - it always throws invalid header exception.

So there is this php-function [idn_to_ascii](http://php.net/manual/de/function.idn-to-ascii.php) which converts domain names to IDNA ASCII format. The problem is that I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

Let's take this email address: testö@domain.com

```
// doesn't work (unknown error):
idn_to_ascii('testö@domain.com') --> xn--test@domain-ufb.com
```

If I just convert the local part of the email address it seems to work:

```
idn_to_ascii('testö') --> xn--test-8qa@domain.com
```

But what if also the domain part contains Umlaute?
e.g. testö@domainö.com

should I do something like this?

```
idn_to_ascii('testö').'@'.idn_to_ascii('domainö.com')
```

Also on the php-homepage someone wrote a comment that you have to skip the high-level domain part (and the official documentation is wrong):
[see here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.idn-to-ascii.php#108900)

```
idn_to_ascii('domainö') // right
idn_to_ascii('domainö.com') // wrong
```

I'm so confused now :|
Someone has experience in that? And the worst thing is: I can't even test it because I don't have an email address with Umlaute.

Comment: Despite the 16 votes, I wouldn't take that user comment too seriously. He only seems to have a vague idea of how basic text encoding works, so I wouldn't trust the higher level information.

Comment: May I ask what do you intend to do with this?utf-8 `.com` to ASCII will still be `.com` I think.

Comment: looking for the same answer, could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

As of 06 December 2022, `testö@domain.com` is **not a valid email address** because the **local part**  (`testö`) can only contain the following ASCII characters:

- Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
- Digits 0 to 9
- Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~
- Character . (dot, period, full stop) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear two or more times consecutively.

---

References:

- [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-3) Section 3
- [RFC 822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-6.1) Section 6.1
- [RFC 5322](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) Section 3.2.3

---

## RFC 3696 Section 3:

> The exact rule is that any ASCII character, including control
> characters, may appear quoted, or in a quoted string.  When quoting
> is needed, the backslash character is used to quote the following
> character.  For example
>
> ```
>   Abc\@def@example.com
> ```
>
> is a valid form of an email address.  Blank spaces may also appear,
> as in
>
> ```
>   Fred\ Bloggs@example.com
> ```
>
> The backslash character may also be used to quote itself, e.g.,
>
> ```
>   Joe.\\Blow@example.com
> ```
>
> In addition to quoting using the backslash character, conventional
> double-quote characters may be used to surround strings.  For example
>
> ```
>   "Abc@def"@example.com
>
>   "Fred Bloggs"@example.com
> ```
>
> are alternate forms of the first two examples above.  These quoted
> forms are rarely recommended, and are uncommon in practice, but, as
> discussed above, must be supported by applications that are
> processing email addresses.  In particular, the quoted forms often
> appear in the context of addresses associated with transitions from
> other systems and contexts; those transitional requirements do still
> arise and, since a system that accepts a user-provided email address
> cannot "know" whether that address is associated with a legacy
> system, the address forms must be accepted and passed into the email
> environment.
>
> Without quotes, local-parts may consist of any combination of
> alphabetic characters, digits, or any of the special characters
>
> ```
>   ! # $ % & ' * + - / = ?  ^ _ ` . { | } ~
> ```
>
> period (".") may also appear, but may not be used to start or end
> the    local part, nor may two or more consecutive periods appear.
> Stated    differently, any ASCII graphic (printing) character other
> than the    at-sign ("@"), backslash, double quote, comma, or square
> brackets may    appear without quoting.  If any of that list of
> excluded characters    are to appear, they must be quoted.  Forms such
> as
>
> ```
>   user+mailbox@example.com
> ```

Comment: In fact there are (as usual) lots of RFCs out there. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization_examples) it's valid as per RFC 6530 (PROPOSED STANDARD). I have no idea of how widespread it is.

Comment: as far is I know it should be valid. Also ZF3 Mail validator says it is a valid mail address. It's probably the best idea to not allow Umlaute in the local part of the mail address. Google also doesn't allow it and a lot of hosters

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit more simple:

```
function email_to_ascii($email) {
    $explode = explode('@', $email);
    return $explode[0].'@'.idn_to_ascii($explode[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function emailToAscii($email) {

    $explodedMail = explode('@', $email);

    $mailName = idn_to_ascii(array_first($explodedMail));

    $mailDomain = last($explodedMail);

    $explodedDomain = explode('.', $mailDomain);

    $secondLvlDomain = idn_to_ascii(array_first($explodedDomain));

    $firstLvlDomain = idn_to_ascii(last($explodedDomain));

    return "$mailName@$secondLvlDomain.$firstLvlDomain";
}
```